# Tense after when

Tags: past-tense

I have these 2 examples:

1. I was sure that you would give me a telegram when you COME to Moscow.
2. I was sure that she would go to the museum again as soon as she HAD the spare time.

   Why in first example we use present tense after "when" and at the second example we use past tense after "as soon as"  ( which is the same expression as "when")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: send a telegram, not give a telegram. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first example would only be valid in one *specific* context, where

> a) The speaker lives in Moscow (otherwise it would be ***go***, not ***come***)
>    b) The addressee hasn't ***yet*** arrived in Moscow
>    c) The speaker originally assumed the addressee ***would*** send a telegram when in Moscow
>    d) The speaker has since discovered that the addressee ***doesn't*** intend to send a telegram

This is a relatively unlikely scenario, so if you know the speaker isn't a native Anglophone you can be pretty sure he's making a mistake, and should have used past tense ***came***.

But it's not the kind of "slip-up" native speakers would be likely to make, so if you know he is one you should assume the above scenario *does* apply.

---

Much the same logic applies to the second example, which *in principle* could also have used present tense *...as soon as she **has** time.* Again, this would imply that *even if she **does** have spare time in the future,* she doesn't plan on going the museum - either she's changed her mind, or the speaker has (recently) discovered he was mistaken about her intentions.

Comment: Come never sounds right here to me.  In the scenario you mention, came is correct, not come.  I don't know the technical term for it, but it feels like such a sentence would be in what I'd call hypothetical past tense.

Comment: @tjp: I said the situation defined by a-d above was a *relatively unlikely scenario*, but obviously it *can* occur, so I don't see how you can baldly assert ***came** is correct, not **come***. As I said, a "mainstream" native speaker wouldn't be likely to "accidentally/ungrammatically" use ***come*** to reference a (hypothetical or actual) past event (though it certainly could occur deliberately in some dialects). But competent native speakers would quite correctly use ***come*** in my scenario. Which is "actual" anticipated future ("hypothetical" if ***when*** were changed to ***if***).

Comment: Yes, I don't know for sure.  I'm not saying it's not technically possible, I'm no professor.  But it sounds completely ridiculous to me, no one would ever say that where I'm from.  I'm just trying to give the perspective of a native speaker.  Technically the sentence _Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo_ is correct, but no one would generate it in real conversation.

Comment: I should try to be more constructive.  This is what one would actually say if they meant what you reference: I was sure that you would give me a telegram _once you came_ to Moscow.

Comment: @tjp: I'm no professor either. But I'm guessing that if you still can't envisage the scenario I outlined above, and see why ***come*** is quite natural/correct *in that scenario*, you're not a native speaker.

Comment: No :(, I'm definitely a native speaker and it sounds wrongity wrong wrong :).  Do you not agree that _once you came_ sounds better than _when you come_?

Comment: I just had a thought about this.  Swap the two halves of the sentence and it's much clearer that it's wrong: _When you come to Moscow, I was sure that you would give me a telegram._

Comment: @tjp: *I [had] intended to meet you when I **come** to London next week, but now I don't think I'll have time.* On reflection, I can see that you *might* use ***came*** there, but to be honest I don't think I would. Maybe my scenario would be clearer to you if we switch to *I **had been** sure... [but now I'm not]* in OP's example.

Comment: I disagree (not saying that this is bad, we wouldn't need a comments section if discussion wasn't necessary).  Again, I would definitely use *came* instead, swap the two parts of the sentence and it sounds off: *When I come to London next week, I [had] intended to meet you, but now I don't think I'll have time.*  This is a tough one.  I think I'm out of my depth here, my intuition isn't enough.

Comment: @tjp: I may be overstating my case here. I don't necessarily think ***came*** would be "incorrect" in the scenario as outlined - mostly I'm concerned to say that I don't think ***come*** is incorrect *either*. In short, it *is* something of a tough one to fully analyse. I'm seriously considering asking about this on ELU (or maybe precisely this point has already been dealt with over there).

Comment: How about *I [had] assumed I would go to Heaven when I **die/died**, but when I look back at all the wicked things I've done, I'm now pretty sure I'll go to Hell [when I die/died]*.

Comment: ...[Here's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438599/verb-tense-for-anticipated-future-in-the-context-of-now-discarded-hypothetical-p) my ELU question, if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

1) I was sure that you would give me a telegram when you COME to Moscow.

2) I was sure that she would go to the museum again as soon as she HAD the spare time. [samples]

**Let's turn these around for a minute** [it's simpler to see]:

1) When you **come** to Moscow, I **was sure you would send me** a telegram.
[That does not follow the rule for tenses. The ideas must refer to the present or the past, not both times.]

That **when** is like an IF (first and second conditional), therefore, we get:

When you **come** to Moscow, I **am sure you will send me** a telegram.

present after when, or, in the past

When you **came** to Moscow, I **was sure you would send me** a telegram.

2)  I was sure that she would go to the museum again as soon as she HAD the spare time.

As soon as she **had spare time**, I **was sure she would go** to the museum.

That is correct. The entire sentence is in the past.

Compare that to:

As soon as **she has spare time**, I **am sure she will** go to the museum.

The overall usage is that either you put an idea in the present and will goes in the main clause, or you put the idea in the past, and would + verb goes in the second clause. Bear in mind that the **would** in those sentences is the past tense of will.

In these examples, I'd tend to use contractions. you'll and you'd, for example.