# Present subjunctive: Verb tense after when

Tags: present-subjunctive

I have seen two related questions. This one [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140307/tense-after-when) has an answer trying to give some general explanation, but I don't understand it well. Let me try with a simple example:

Text me back when you (be) back at the office.

The context I am thinking of is: I have just been to your office but you were not there and I want to meet you in person. Is it clear?

In my mother tongue that would be a subjunctive,  but unfortunately English does not have.

How about *when you be back at your office*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Be" is the form of "to be" that is traditionally described as the present subjunctive.  (Not everyone likes the term.)  It is a verb form that is the same as the bare infinitive and which is used in mandative constructions (especially in American English but maybe increasingly in British English, e.g. *he asked that she leave*) and in certain set phrases (*so be it*) and in a few very formal, somewhat old-fashioned constructions (*whether it be red or blue*).

That said, English doesn't use a subjunctive of any kind in this context:

> Text me back when you (be) back at the office.

"Be" is wrong here.  It has to be:

> Text me back when you **are** back at the office

or

> Text me back when you'**re** back at the office.

("In the office" is perhaps more likely, though "at the office" is possible.)